# Winforms web browser, send JSON with url?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, web, browser

I am working on a small little project and was wondering if it would be possible to run a JSON command with the web browser tool. If anyone has any intel regarding this please share It would solve so many problems!

```
json=1&type=groupInvite&group=103582791439684988&sessionID=d0b0158ab51db4524e33642f&invitee=76561198021437701
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON command".

Comment: What else too call it if it looks like this "json=1&type=groupInvite&group=103582791439684988&sessionID=d0b0158ab51db4524e33642f&invitee=76561198021437701"

Comment: You mean your "payload" as GET? 
Don't do it please.

Comment: Why not? And what if I REALLY wanted to do it how can I do it?